# passing two elements to function

Tags: javascript

I want to pass two elements in the same event to a function so as to display both elements upon clicking a link button.

this is the function

```
function showMenu(elmnt)
        {
            document.getElementById(elmnt).style.visibility="visible";
        }
```

These are the two element I want to display. Only the first one is displayed. How can I display both
at the same time by clicking the button.

```
<div id="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" onClick="showMenu('scroll')" onClick="showMenu('oath')" >Oath</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Apply</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function showMenu(elmnt1, elmnt2) {
    document.getElementById(elmnt1).style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById(elmnt2).style.visibility="visible";
}

onClick="showMenu('scroll', 'oath')"
```

or:

```
function showMenu(elements) {
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById(elements[i]).style.visibility="visible";
    }
}

onClick="showMenu(['scroll', 'oath'])"
```

This all could be done much more elegantly by attaching the event handlers using Javascript etc., you should look into [unobtrusive Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Comment: A variation on your second option is to use the `arguments` object within your function and then just call it as `showMenu('scroll,'oath');`.

Comment: @nnnnnn - see my answer - I prefer to pass an array too

Comment: @mplungjan - I was just offering another option. If you use `arguments` the function still handles any number of ids with a simple loop through `arguments` but the call is slightly simpler. But then using an array parameter is also useful if you are storing the list of ids somewhere before calling the function.

Comment: I understand. I was tempted myself to use the arguments, but I vaguely remembered something about deprecation. However it is not the arguments that are deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just use `onClick="showMenu('scroll', 'oath');return false;"` and then have the function:

```
function showMenu(el1, el2)
    {
        document.getElementById(el1).style.visibility="visible";
        document.getElementById(el2).style.visibility="visible";
    }
```

The preferred method of attaching events is using `addEventListener` instead of attributes. You need to add IE support using `attachEvent`. [MDN - addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener).

Comment: True - although due to the `href` being `#` there wouldn't be a page reload. Updated.

Comment: There USED to be be an invisible page unload - I just tried it, and it seems you are correct in Fx5 at least http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/EUheF/ - but try clicking the links at the bottom of the fiddle now

Comment: Ah, good point. I guess because the named location doesn't exist it scrolls back to the top. One to remember in future, although for the past few years I have been using the event argument for cancelling default behaviour. Good to learn something new.

Answer (score 1):

```
function showMenu(elmnt1, elmnt2)
{
   document.getElementById(elmnt1).style.visibility="visible";
   document.getElementById(elmnt2).style.visibility="visible";
}

<li><a href="#" onclick="showMenu('scroll', 'oath'); return false;">Oath</a></li>
```

The `return false` is to stop the standard event the browser would perform when hitting on the link.

Answer (score 1):

Passing an array so we can have an "on" as second argument

```
function showHide(elmnt,on) {
  if (elmnt.length==null) elmnt=[elmnt]; 
  for (var i=0,n=elmnt.length;i<n;i++) {
    var item = document.getElementById(elmnt[i]);
    if (item) item.style.visibility=on?"visible":"hidden";
  }
  return false;
}
```

Multiple:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return showHide(['scroll','oath'],1)">Show</a>
<a href="#" onclick="return showHide(['scroll','oath'],0)">Hide</a>
```

single items:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return showHide('scroll',1)">Show</a>
<a href="#" onclick="return showHide('scroll',0)">Hide</a>
```

---

Alternatively, pass *on* as first argument and, as suggested elsewhere, loop over the [arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/functions_and_function_scope/arguments) object from item 1

```
function showHide() {
  var on = arguments[0]
  for (var i=1,n=arguments.length;i<n;i++) { // from 1
    var item = document.getElementById(arguments[i]);
    if (item) item.style.visibility=on?"visible":"hidden";
  }
  return false;
}


<a href="#" onclick="return showHide(1,'scroll','oath')">Show</a>
<a href="#" onclick="return showHide(0,'scroll','oath')">Hide</a>
```

---

Lastly (getting into jQuery territory here) pass an object to allow selective on and off

```
function showHide(obj) {
  for (var o in obj) {
    var item = document.getElementById(o);
    if (item) item.style.visibility=obj[o]?"visible":"hidden";
  }
  return false;
}


<a href="#" onclick="return showHide({'scroll':1,'oath':0})">Show scroll, hide oath</a>
<a href="#" onclick="return showHide({'scroll':0,'oath':1})">Hide scroll, Show oath</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
function showMenu(elmnt1, elmnt2)

{

document.getElementById(elmnt1).style.visibility="visible";
            document.getElementById(elmnt2).style.visibility="visible";

}

<li><a href="#" onClick="showMenu('scroll', 'oath')">Oath</a></li>
```

Comment: Indent your code by two spaces! Read the help on the edit screen.

Comment: 4 spaces - but simpler to highlight and click {}